# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" Error while trying to add Https Service from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, ssl, https

I am trying to add Service Https Service Reference to Visual Studio.

The https://thelinkiamtrying.com/Service.svc link opens in browser without problem. But when I try to add it through Visual studio interface, (Add Service Reference) I get the following error:

"There was an error downloading 'https://thelinkiamtrying.com/Service.svc/databin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://thelinkiamtrying.com/Service.svc'.
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'thelinkiamtrying.com'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

What should I do to add this Service?

If you just show me that how can I call it without using the interface and from codebehind, that would help too.

Comment: Is your site in HTTPS ?

Comment: @User.Anonymous No, I just created a Windows Application and tried to add a reference. I tried same with Web Application too, and got the same result. I am not the owner of the .svc Url, do I need to set things on my IIS too?

Comment: Yes, just add binding https and localhost IIS certificate.

Comment: @User.Anonymous How do I do it? Do I need to have a paid certificate, etc?

Comment: inside IIS, right click on your website and choose "manage binding" -> Add  -> https type -> choose localhost certificate. Localhost certificate is free but untrusted. For production, you can get free trusted certificate at https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and resolved this by using another version of Visual Studio. VS 2012 did not let me add service reference with the exact same error message, but VS 2015 added it with no errors. Then I was able to save the project and open it again in VS 2012.